# Django get resource in Json

Tags: django-views, getjson

```js
import json
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from menu.models import *

def Database(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
       menus = Menu.objects.all()
       return toJSON(serialize(menus))

def serialize(menus):
    serialized = []
    for obj in menus:
        serialized.append(obj.serializer())
    return serialized

def toJSON(menus, status=200):
    j = json.dumps(menus, ensure_ascii=False)
    return HttpResponse(j, status=status, content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8')
```

I make my `views.py` like this, but it returns just `[]`, How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

did you mean you don't get key-value pair, instead you get just list ?

use

```
j = json.dumps({"menus":menus}, ensure_ascii=False)
```

instead of

```
j = json.dumps(menus, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: oh I solve this. it just return [] because I don't post anything to menu.:)